# How to display selected value in dropdown menu example "please pick and select"

Tags: reactjs

How to display the `selected` value "please pick and select" in this dropdown menu example?

The given code is not working:

```
<div className="col-md-6">
  <select
    className="form-select"
    aria-label="Default select example"
  >
  {" "}
  {this.state.values.map((obj) => {
    return (
      <option selected ="please pick and select" key={obj.id} value={obj.id}> 
        {obj.name}
      </option>
     );
   })}
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Was my answer useful, or do you still need help?

Comment: state value is not updating correctly, but works only if we added -1 to the output selection You have {values[selected] ? <>"{values[selected].name -1}"</> : <>nothing</>} selected. Bur this also returns nothing if 10th item is selected

Comment: Everything works fine for me, even with more items: https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-kirch-y3cbff?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an array of objects like this:

```js
[
  { id: 0, name: "one" },
  { id: 1, name: "two" },
  { id: 2, name: "three" }
]
```

You can display those as options in a select like so, with the "please select an option" in a separate option element:

```
<div>
<select value={selected} onChange={handleChange}>
  <option value={-1} disabled>
    please select an option
  </option>
  {values.map((obj) => {
    return (
      <option key={obj.id} value={obj.id}>
        {obj.name}
      </option>
    );
  })}
</select>
</div>
```

Then in the `handleChange` function, you can set a state that stores which item is selected (here I'm storing the `id` of the `obj`, which in this case is the same as the index of the `values` array):

```js
const [selected, setSelected] = useState(-1);

function handleChange(event) {
  setSelected(event.target.value);
}
```

And then you can use that to output the selection:

```
<div>
  You have {values[selected] ? <>"{values[selected].name}"</> : <>nothing</>} selected.
</div>
```

[image: Edit festive-blackwell-es2ske]

Check out the React [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume your **state.values** is like this:

```
[
  {
    id: 0,
    name: "First value"
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Second value"
  }
]
```

In order to show the "please pick and select" as the default value of the select element (placeholder), it's good to not have it in your data. Instead you can render an extra option along with your data options and then choose the value as the selected value of the select element:

```js
<select className="form-select" aria-label="Default select example">
  <option value={-1} selected>
    Please pick and select
  </option>
  {
    this.state.values.map((obj) => {
      return (
        <option key={obj.id} value={obj.id}>
          {obj.name}
        </option>
      );
    })
  }
</select>
```

If you want to have control over the selected value as well, you can use **useState** and declare a state for your selected value and change it whenever the selected value is changed:

```js
const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState(-1);

const handleOnChange = (event) => {
  setSelectedValue(event.target.value);
}

return (
  <select value={selectedValue} onChange={handleOnChange} className="form-select" aria-label="Default select example">
    <option value={-1}>
      Please pick and select
    </option>
    {
      this.state.values.map((obj) => {
        return (
          <option key={obj.id} value={obj.id}>
            {obj.name}
          </option>
        );
      })
    }
  </select>
);
```

Read more [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-set-default-value-in-select-using-reactjs/).